# Commit on top of a custom GO package

Tags: git, go, github

I am using `sha3` package inside a forked `go` project. I am using a special feature that does not exist in that package and I had to download a  file from `gist`, insert it into the `sha3` package and compile it.
Everything is working fine. However, anyone who wants to run my code, they have to get that file and insert it into standard `sha3` package first, install the package and run my project. 
What is the best way that I can include the `gist` file and `sha3` into my commit, so anyone can just clone and run it? Here is the file path:

```
workspace-
         |_src__
                |_github.com
                |          |_myproject
                |                     |_codes
                |                     |_.git
                |_golang.org
                           |_x
                             |_crypto
                                    |_sha3
                                         |_custom.go
```

Comment: I see two solutions (at least) use the vendor directory to version your custom crypto package inside your project, otherwise make a fork ang `go get` it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since go 1.5, you can put a [`vendor` folder](https://blog.gopheracademy.com/advent-2015/vendor-folder/) at the root of your project (`workspace/src/github.com/myproject/vendor`). This folder is an import path. When building, `go build` will first look for packages inside your vendor folder and if not found, will look inside your `$GOPATH`.

You can copy your custom `golang.org/x/crypto` package inside your vendor folder and add it to your favorite VCS.

The other solution would be to make a fork of the [golang.org/x/crypto](https://github.com/golang/crypto) repository like `github.com/user/mycrypto` and use the `go get` command to get the code like this:

```
go get github.com/user/mycrypto
```

That being said, VonC is right, it's a good practice to use a dependency manager as it will keep track of what version of libraries you have installed, and it allows better portability.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [`dep`](https://github.com/golang/dep):

- Remove your golang.org folder, and go to your project folder.
- Then try `dep ensure`.

If you don't have go dep installed, type first:

```
go get -u github.com/golang/dep/cmd/dep
```

That will vendor your dependency: see "[Understanding and using the vendor folder](https://blog.gopheracademy.com/advent-2015/vendor-folder/)".

Comment: But OP wants to maintain a modified version of the upstream package. Using `dep` in this way would imply modifying the vendored package and that doesn't seem optimal. I think a straight fork with the modifications would be clearer.